# Change upload range from 100% to 90% image upload

Tags: javascript

I optimize images after they upload. I need to change 100%  to 90% because image stuck for a while.
How do I change this to show 90 % after image upload not 100%.

```
plup_uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {

                document.getElementById( "thumb-holder-" + file.id ).innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent +  "%</span>";
            });
```

Comment: Jut put in a condition when it reaches 90 % do not update it keep it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply multiply `file.percent` by 0.90 when displaying the progress:

```
plup_uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {

    document.getElementById( "thumb-holder-" + file.id ).innerHTML = '<span>' + (file.percent * .9) +  "%</span>";
});
```

To format the progress with one decimal only, use `Math.floor`:

```
Math.floor(file.percent * .9 * 10) /10
```

Comment: This works perfect, just I get long number when files are uploading: Like 38.4000000 %,  How do I change it to show just not more then 3 numbers. For example 38.4%